# can we connect AWS ec2 instance which is having only private IP with the other ec2 instance with a public IP ? from putty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ip

I have just started my career in the IT field and currently learning new technologies like AWS.
I have a small doubt and it will be really helpful for me if anyone can help me with it.

"Can we connect ec2 instance which is having only private IP with the other ec2 instance with a public IP"

In Putty, I have logged into an EC2 instance (With public IP) and tried to ssh into other EC2 instances (which is having only private IP) by mentioning its private IP Address, but I wasn't able to login to that.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Are both Amazon EC2 instances in the **same subnet**? What do you mean by "wasn't able to login"? Did you receive an error message? Did it fail immediately, or take some time before it failed? What is the configuration of the Security Group on the 'private' instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this (providing security groups and network configuration allows).

The first method (and more prefered) is through a private to private connection, just because an instance has a public IP does not mean it is inaccessible from private inbound connections. If they share the same VPC as long as your [security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html)/[NACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) allow inbound from the private IP range you will be able to connect to the instance via its private IP.

If the instances share a different VPC (or even account) you can connect between using either [transit gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/transit-gateway/) or a [single peering connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html), then whitelist the IP range of the source. A caveat is that these separate networks cannot be peered if they have a crossover in network address ranges (you would need to [create a secondary range](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-resize) to deal with this).

The alternative is to use either a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or [NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) and then bind this to the [route table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html) for your instance for the `0.0.0.0/0` route. You would then need to whitelist in the public instances security group the public EIP of the NAT. This is less preferable as it requires communication across the internet.